# Date format Issue in Java

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

I am using below simple date format in backend java to format the date which was given by user through user interface.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
SimpleDateFormat sdfMonthYear = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdfMonthYearDisplay = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
```

When It's deployed in my local machine It populates correct month value as Jan , Feb, Mar,Apr etc.But The proj now deployed in other server ex in Swedan's system .So now I am getting the month value as Maj instead of May and Okt instead of Oct.I have verifed that this month format is swedan based.I want a generic way of month format even Its deployed in any country like Jan ,Feb,may,Oct etc.

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the locale when you create the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.US);
```

Note that using one specific `Locale` for all users is typically appropriate for machine-to-machine communication - when you're parsing an ISO-8601 format, for example. To display a date to a user, you would normally use their locale *and* fetch an appropriate format, e.g.

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, userLocale);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.YourCountryCode);
```

Will change it to your local date time

For Codes Follow :

[Locale Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use another constructor of `SimpleDateFormat` which includes `Locale` :

[`SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29)

> here **locale** is the locale whose date format symbols should be used

like :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need this constructor `SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)` of [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)